# Possible to use Youtube API to track user position?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I have not been able to find a solution.

I have embeded youtube videos on my site. I want to use youtube api to know exactly where my viewers are in a video. When they are at 1:00 (1 minute), the youtube API will let me know so I can execute a javascript command.

Is this possible? Can youtube api communicate user status every second? Is there a better solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example at

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

does something extremely similar.  Waits 6 seconds instead of 60, but otherwise...

One problem to be aware of, though; despite the documentation from YouTube saying that you can create a YT.Player instance against an iframe that you already written onto the page, the event listener stuff doesn't work dependably unless you use their Javascript to actually write out the iframe code for you.  Every few months it seems that they break this, then fix it a few weeks later.  I'd built my use of this around having jquery write out the appropriate iframe, and finally a few days ago re-engineered it to use the 'preferred' way YouTube likes of having YouTube write the iframe.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen for the onStateChange event (https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events) to determine when the video has began playing. At that point you can set a one second interval that keeps track of how many seconds have elapsed. If the user pauses playback, simply clear the interval. When 60 seconds has elapsed call whatever function you wish.